# How to use array variable in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array and I want to put same array and other array inside of the first array.

```
var arr=["a","b","c",arr,arr2];
var arr2=["a","b"];

var arr3=[];
arr3=arr[3];
```

When I print out arr, I can see
 `["a","b","c",,]`

But if I print out arr3, The result is undefined.

How can I fix it?

Comment: This can't possibly work. You're assigning arrays to other arrays before they even exist.

Comment: `arr` is undefined when you're creating the array that will be assigned to `arr`.

Comment: The result is `undefined` because the variables are clearly not defined, no suprise there !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do this in the right order:

```
var arr1 = [];
var arr2 = [ "a", "b" ];


// Now arr1 and arr2 are defined so you can throw them into another array:

var arr3 = [ "a", "b", "c", arr1, arr2 ];
```

Answer (score 1):

You've defined `arr` as part of itself - `arr[3]` is `arr`. But at the time, `arr` doesn't exist yet, so it comes out as `undefined`.